# Not allowed to load local resource meteor app

Tags: html, css, image, meteor

I want to add a background image to my meteor webapp:

```
background: url('../public/img/car.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

But then I get the following error message:

```
jquery.js?hash=c334cf5…:3662 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/project/app/public/car.jpg
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using cordova? Please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503179/cordova-meteor-app-not-allowed-to-load-local-resource) answer

Comment: No I'm not using cordova, its a standart meteor webapp

Comment: Are you using browser-policy? Does the background actually display? Though the issue is probably as Christian said bellow.

Comment: turned out to be a meteor specific folder thing. see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer here:
[meteor app: images not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353568/meteor-app-images-not-loading)

> Files in /public are served to the client as-is

So I had to exclude the file path and just type `/car.png`

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be misunderstanding the use of the `public` folder (see the doc on [directory structure](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories)). Anything in that folder will be served statically on the `/` URL. So I think all you need to change is this:

```
background: url('/img/car.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
```